# Publishing SDL Tridion Content to 3rd Party Delivery Platforms

Tags: content-delivery, publishing

I am writing integration with a third party SaaS based content delivery platform. I have no access to the platform's servers with the exception of using the existing web services API and FTP functionality offered by the platform.

The obvious way to store Tridion published data in a custom way is to write a custom storage/deployer extension, but for the reasons stated above, the deployer cannot be installed on the destination servers. As such we are considering publishing to the local file system, and installing the custom deployer on the CM server, and having it distribute the necessary to the delivery servers via FTP and Web Service calls.

What are the pros and cons of such an approach, and would there a better extension point such as the transport service? Any ideas/suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: Can you disclose which SaaS based content delivery platform it is. Or otherwise explain it's limitations and such? The suggestion of publishing make me think the SAAS platform is rather static, maybe even static HTML?

Comment: I stores and streams both images and video - So extremely static.

Comment: How its different from directly publishing to FTP & is there any issue in publishing directly?

Comment: Publishing via FTP will send a publish transaction package (zip file). You need a Deployer to unpack the file. I have no option to install such a Deployer on the receiving server.

Answer (score 8):

In a previous project we had a scenario where the deployer was installed onto the CMS machine and the files published to the file system (no use of content delivery database).

We had a custom script that would run once a day to check the stored files and ftp them to a specific location for a third-party application that was configured to pick them up.

In terms of the publishing workflow this worked great (and is still working today about 7 years later!).

Some things to note:

- The script contained a lot of extra checking to ensure the files can be sent and are delivered, if they couldn't the original files were not overwritten
- There was no checking in place to ensure content authors had published all related content items together - perhaps this is good user case for 'bundles' ?
- The published content was not dynamic in any sense, content was stored as static html with some minor js

I'm happy to share the ftp scripting and configuration ... If I can dig it out :)